# Reducing quartic equations to quadratic

Tags: quadratics

I'm trying to re-learn basic math/algebra, and I can't get passed one question concerned with reducing quartic equation to a quadratic:

> Find, correct to 3 significant figures, all the roots of the equation $8x^4 - 8x^2 + 1 = \frac12\sqrt 3$

I've tried substitution:

Let $y = 8x^2$, making:

$$
y^2 -y + 1 = \frac12\sqrt 3 \\
(y-1)^2 = \frac12\sqrt 3 \\
y-1 = {\sqrt{\frac12\sqrt 3}} \\
y-1 = ±0.931 \\
y = 1.931\text{ or } 0.069
$$

Therefore:

$$
x = √({1.931 \over 8}) \ or \ √({0.069 \over 8}) \\
x = 0.491 \ or \ 0.093
$$

But, as you can see on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8x%5E4-8x%5E2%2B1%3D%281%2F2%29%E2%88%9A3), the roots are ±0.991 and ±0131.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did not substitute $y = 8x^2$ correctly.  See if you can figure out the error.

Comment: Try writing $8x^4-8x^2+1 = 2(4x^4-4x^2+1)-1 = 2(y-1)^2-1$ where $y = 2x^2$ to see if matters improve any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$8x^4 - 8x^2 + 1 = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt 3$$
$$16x^4-16x^2+2-\sqrt3=0$$
$$(4x^2)^2-4\cdot4x^2+2-\sqrt3=0$$
$4x^2=y,x=\pm\frac{\sqrt y}{2}$
$$y^2-4y+2-\sqrt3=0$$
$$(y-2)^2=2+\sqrt3$$
$$y=2\pm\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$$
$$x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}}{2}$$

Answer (score 6):

Note that $$y = 8x^2\;\implies\;y^2 = 64 x^4$$

In addition, putting aside that error, you incorrectly factored $$y^2 - y +1 \neq (y - 1)^2 = y^2 - 2x + 1$$

Try substituting $y = x^2$ and then divide each side of the resulting equation by $8$.